# Using Navigator without context

Tags: flutter

I have a class that wraps http calls (get, post, delete).
What I need to achieve is a way to check every api response to be able to force a logout if, for example, a token is expired.

Let's say I'm logged in my app and my token expires; I then try to list my posts with a call like this:

`var results = api.get('http://api.site.com/user/123/posts')`

```
get(String endpoint) async {
  return http.get(endpoint,
    headers: headers(),
  ).then((response) {
    var result = json.decode(response.body);
    if (result['force_logout'] == true) {
      UserServices.logout(); // delete secure storage data and other stuff
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/login', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
    }
    return result;
  });
}
```

Inside my api get method I would like to be able to perform the user logout and navigate to the login screen, but how can I do it without having a context?

Comment: You can't do that. You need to bind your `api` to the context somehow

Comment: Maybe passing `context` in every api method call?

Comment: Bad idea. A custom class would be better

Comment: What do you mean? Can you provide an example?